# If column terms match text in range B equal to or less then, insert the other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

The attached photo illustrates roughly what I am trying to do, top and bottom images illustrates a collection of 12k pictures and I need to associate the `id` depicted in the middle portion of the attached image.

I know I have been going with VBA but a formula might also work.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: screenshot of data]

And this is code I tried with:

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim CompareRange As Variant, ToCompare As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
    Set CompareRange = Worksheets("ID_proptitle").Range("B1:A500")
    Set ToCompare = Worksheets("pictures").Range("B1:C500")
    For Each x In ToCompare
        For Each y In CompareRange
            If x = y Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the unique lookup value should be everything in the picture name less the `=0001` (or `=0002`, etc.), then an `INDEX` & `MATCH` formula should do the trick.  Try the following:

```
=INDEX(ID_proptitle!A:B,MATCH(LEFT(A2,LEN(A1)-4),ID_proptitle!B:B,0),1)
```

It looks in the `ID_proptitle` sheet for the matching `prop_title` name, based on the value in the `post_title` field, less the last 4 characters (`=0001`, etc.), then returns the corresponding value in Column A

Comment: HEY sorry for the late upvote ... here ya go worked great btw

Answer (score 1):

Since the naming of the pictures does not always seem to be following the same convention (sometimes money values are also included?), you could try the following:

```
=INDEX(ID_proptitle!$A:$A,MATCH(LEFT($A2,LEN($A2)*0.7),ID_proptitle!$B:$B,1),1)
```

The match however does not do a precise matching, so if you have properties that are named very similarly, you need to be careful. You can also play around with the 0.7.

Comment: Also worked out for me, a bit late but the shame in downvotes had me avoiding this ... lol but deserved+